# Como criar um arquivo de configuração .BAT no windows?

Tags: windows, variáveis, batch, terminal, prompt

Estou automatizando alguns processos em um servidor Windows, e gostaria de criar alguns arquivos .bat para isso porém para tal seria necessário que o .BAT fosse capas de ler um arquivo de configuração então eu fiz o seguinte:

arquivo get.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal
@if not exist "%1" (
    echo Config file not found in "%1"
    exit /B
)

@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in (%1) do (
    set %%A=%%B
)

echo %folder%
```

e criei um arquivo de configuração chamdo winscp.conf com os seguintes dados:

```
folder    %appData%\winscp
version   5.7.4
visit     http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/
download  http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/files/WinSCP/5.7.4/winscp574.zip
```

e então eu chamo o .bat assim:

```
get winscp.conf
```

Até ai tudo bem a variavel é lida e criada exatamente como eu gostaria, o porém esta no uso de variáveis de ambiente, eu gostaria de que app data fosse interpretado e estocado na variável mas ao invés de ter algo parecido com isso

```
C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\winscp
```

eu recebo isso:

```
%appData%\winscp
```

Resumindo: eu gostaria que o %appData% fosse interpretado mas, ou invés disso eu estou recebendo o valor literal.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Muito esperto, heim. Já pensou em usar essa criatividade com o **Powershell**? É muito mais poderoso e mais simples. Agora minha dúvida: qual o problema em obter `%appData%\winscp` no valor da variável já que este é um caminho válido para você ler e gravar arquivos ao longo do script?

Comment: O problema é que se eu tento executar algo do tipo mkdir %folder% ao invés de criar a pasta utilizando o caminho da variável de ambiente ele cria uma pasta relativa ao .bat. ele cria uma pasta com o nome %appData%.

Estou pensando em fazer isso com Cli PHP ou NodeJS, achei que seria mais simples com um arquivo .bat

Comment: Tem opção de VBS, também. A vantagem de .BAT, PowerShell e VBS é que são nativos do Windows, não precisa de nenhuma ferramenta adicional pra rodar. De qualquer modo é estranho. Eu testei agora `set teste=%appdata%\teste` seguido de `mkdir %teste%` e foi criada corretamente a pasta `C:\Users\Caffé\AppData\Roaming\teste`.

Comment: Sim ele cria normalmente se estive no mesmo arquivo .bat, o problema é quando eu busco do arquivo .conf, se puder e tiver disposição, tente recriar o meu senário com o arquivo .bat e o arquivo .conf.

Comment: Realmente curioso... Repliquei a questão no SOen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592509/how-to-set-a-variable-with-an-environment-variable-read-from-a-text-file Acompanhe lá.

Comment: Problema resolvido no SOen :-) Resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora eu ache criativa a sua solução, eu utilizo outra técnica para ter uma espécie de arquivo de configuração comum para os meus arquivos de lote .BAT (ou *batch files*):

O meu arquivo de configuração é ele próprio um arquivo .BAT, mais ou menos assim (arquivo *Setup_Prod.bat*):

```
set HOME=\\servidor\pasta_prod
set ENV=PROD
set DB=dabase_producao
set PASSWORD=senha_producao
```

Então eu tenho diferentes arquivos de configuração para diferentes ambientes, e passo o arquivo de configuração como parâmetro para os meus scripts. Por exemplo:

```
call AtualizaBanco.bat Setup_Prod.bat
```

No comando acima, *"Setup_Prod.bat"* é um parâmetro, uma string mesmo, passada para o script *AtualizaBanco.bat*.

A primeria coisa que o arquivo *AtualizaBanco.bat* deve fazer é usar o arquivo de configuração para setar as variáveis. Então na primeira linha do *AtualizaBanco.bat* eu tenho:

```
call %1%
```

Na linha acima eu estou invocando como script o primeiro parâmetro recebido.

Agora, no arquivo *AtualizaBanco.bat*, eu consumo as variáveis, exemplo:

```
copy %HOME%\*.sql
```

## Conclusão

Em vez de fazer um loop no começo do script principal setando as variáveis de acordo com o arquivo de configuração, eu faço do arquivo de configuração ele próprio um arquivo de lote .BAT, e invoco este .BAT de configuração no começo do meu script principal.

O seu problema provavelmente está na forma como você seta as variáveis dentro do loop. Utilizando esta técnica que eu propuz você elimina o loop, eliminando o problema.

Reforço porém a minha sugestão de usar **Windows Powershell** ou **Visual Basic Script (VBS)** para resolver este tipo de problema (de preferência o Powershell), pois estas são ferramentas mais poderosas e que proporcionam um código mais simples, expressivo, e fácil de escrever.

## Edit: corrigindo o seu código

As [respostas obtidas no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592509/how-to-set-a-variable-with-an-environment-variable-read-from-a-text-file) indicam a solução do problema:

Em vez de:

```
set %%A=%%B
```

Faça:

```
call set %%A=%%B
```

O `call` faz a variável `%appData%` ser expandida antes de o seu valor ser utilizado.

Comment: Valeu a dica, acredito realmente que preciso de algo mais poderoso, vou analisar as alternativas. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção.